# repeated measures linear regression R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4

I have an experiment with 16 subjects. Each subject has 3 base line measurements of a continuous variable Age, BMI and bloodlevelA

Each subject then undergoes the same study protocol of treatment over 5 days (days 1-5).

On each day a further blood measurement is made (bloodlevelB).

mydata is in long format with one row each measurement of bloodlevelB

```
subject = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "two")
Age = c(56,56,56,56,56,65)
BMI = c(28,28,28,28,28,32)
bloodlevelA = c(9,9,9,9,9,6)
bloodlevelB = c(12.4, 15.2, 26.1, 18.5, 16.2, 11.1)
mydata = data.frame(subject , Age , BMI , bloodlevelA , bloodlevelB)
```

I would like like to know if Age, BMI or bloodlevelA predict BloodlevelB taking into account the repeated measurements on each day of the treatment protocol. I am able to do this for the entire data set.

```
fit1 = lm(BloodlevelB ~ Age , data = my data)
fit2 = lm(BloodlevelB ~ BMI , data = my data)
fit3 = lm(BloodlevelB ~ bloodlevelA , data = my data)
```

assuming BMI and bloodlevelA are significant predictors

```
multifit = lm(BloodlevelB ~ BMI+bloodlevelA, data = mydata)
```

Using lmer or similar I would like to include the fact that bloodlevelB has been measured on each participant 5 times - once on each day of the 5 day protocol. The day of the treatment protocol will likely influence bloodlevelB due to the nature of the treatment and the within subject repeated measures should strengthen the study design.

thanks